# Multisig address Vs Contract address

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, erc-20, exchanges, multisignature

I happened to deposit a new token "**POWR**" on bittrex exchange and when clicked to generate a new address i got a `0xa217f4c09ff1a27be0724f1efaf0fc5e87ca3031`
When i checked the address in [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa217f4c09ff1a27be0724f1efaf0fc5e87ca3031) the i found it aas a smart contract address, so i got confused that why did i got a smart contract address to deposit my funds to.

I asked some of my developers and then they told me that it is a multisignature address.
So my question is how can we identify if a specific address is smart contract or a multisignature address.

Answer (score 1):

A multisig is a type of contract, they aren't two different types of addresses.a multisig is just a contract that requires multiple private keys to do something. Usually the "something" is just withdrawing/moving eth or tokens.